# I use Google Tag Manager to fire tags on my website.Variables "undefined" in custom code for any version of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager to fire tags on my website.  The tags are firing correctly in all browsers except Internet Explorer (any version). What is happening is that the GTM macro is not getting populated in my custom Javascript when using Internet Explorer.  However, if I refresh the page they get populated.  Based on this I assume the issue is that the tag is firing before the DOM is completely loaded.  I am using `{{event}} equals gtm.dom` in the "Rule".  I have also tried to use `{{event}} equals gtm.load` in the "Rule", but that doesn't work either.  Here is how I have the GTM Macro, Rule and Tag defined.  The thing that is even more odd is that when I test the tag in "Preview" mode in GTM, it works every time, no issues.  But once I publish it, it no longer works unless I refresh the page.  What am I doing wrong?

**Macro Name:** PDP-ProdID
**Macro Type:** Custom JavaScript
**Custom Javascript:**

```
function () {
    var pdp_prodid = document.getElementsByName('sku')[0].value;
    return pdp_prodid;
}
```

**Rule Name:** FullSite_Product_Detail_Page - Footer
**Conditions:**
`{{url}} contains gohastings.com/product/`
`{{event}} equals gtm.dom`

**Tag Name:** Fetchback_Smart_Pixel-Remarketing-PDP
**Tag Type:** Custom HTML Tag
**HTML:**
`<iframe src='{{protocol}}://pixel.fetchback.com/serve/fb/pdj?cat=&name=landing&sid=6288&browse_products={{PDP-ProdID}}' scrolling='no' width='1' height='1' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' frameborder='0'></iframe>`

**Firing Rules:** FullSite_Product_Detail_Page - Footer

**Site:** qa.gohastings.com (However, I have some issues on my QA site, so use this link as it will take you directly to a product detail page.
**http://qa.gohastings.com/product/BOOK/Fifty-Shades-of-Grey-Bk-1/sku/287464232.uts** (product detail page)

**Result of tag on first page load**
`<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://pixel.fetchback.com/serve/fb/pdj?cat=&name=landing&sid=6288&browse_products=undefined" frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="no">`

**Result of tag after page reload**
`<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://pixel.fetchback.com/serve/fb/pdj?cat=&name=landing&sid=6288&browse_products=287464232" frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="no">`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem tracking e-commerce transactions with Google Analytics. The `gtm.dom` event would fire before I set up the transaction details. What I ended up doing was trigger a custom event after I set up the data layer instead of using the `gtm.dom` event.

You can change the rule condition to `{{event}} equals myPageLoad`, then after the page loads and you know everything is ready that you need (using `$(document).ready(...)` in jQuery, for example), call:

```
dataLayer.push({ event: 'myPageLoad' });
```

Comment: Since I don't have access to the source code and my IT department doesn't have time to make any changes right now, I had to get creative.  So, I used my CMS to update the Footer on my website to include this script as the very last thing. `<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'PageLoaded' });
</script>` It works perfectly in all browsers now.