# Google Tag Manager - read cookie just after they are set

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to read cookie that are set by Google Tag Manager.

Right now if Google Tag Manager is loaded first time for end-user I can't read cookies (because it happens later, but not immediately).

Is there a good way (callback?) that can help me to read cookies once they are set? This issue is only relevant if user visits page first time.

Comment: you can use the pageload event like in this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552560/load-google-tag-manager-synchronously

Comment: Are the cookies you want to read set from withing a Trigger in Google Analytics and/or from a third-party script?

Comment: @PhilippeSawicki they are from Google Analytics

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to read the `__utm*` or  `_ga` cookies?

Comment: @PhilippeSawicki _ga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments below the question, I would suggest the following solution (assuming you also send *Pageviews* to Google Analytics). Examples are based on [Simo Ahava](https://www.simoahava.com/)'s (excellent) blog.

(Please note that I haven't had the opportunity to test it thoroughly, as I am currently unable to create a complete test case for this setup -- there might be some hiccups)

## 1. Create a Variable to read the *_ga* cookie

> Reference: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-magic-google-tag-manager/#1-client-time

This will return the value for the cookie with name specified (be careful in where you use the value read, as there is always a chance that cookies are rejected by the User's browser policies).

Create a new Variable, with:

- **Variable Name** of `GA Cookie`
- **Cookie Name** of `_ga`

[image: Reading Cookies with Google Tag Manager]
<sub>(source: [simoahava.com](https://www.simoahava.com/images/2015/01/1st-party-cookie-1.jpg))</sub>

## 2. Define a *callBackFunction*

> Reference: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-magic-google-tag-manager/#8-hitcallback-with-a-universal-analytics-tag & https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-magic-google-tag-manager/#6-get-clientid-using-_ga-cookie

This callback function will be executed right after the *Pageview* is sent (i.e. after the `_ga` cookie is set).

Create a Custom JavaScript Macro with the following code:

```
function () {
   return function () {
      // Code to be executed in order to read the cookie:
      try {
         var gaCookie = {{GA Cookie}};

         // Do what you need to with the cookie here:
         // ...

         return gaCookie;
      } catch (e) {
         console.log('No Universal Analytics cookie found.');
         return 'N/A';
      }
   }
}
```

## 3. Define a *hitCallback* after sending the Pageview

> Reference: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-magic-google-tag-manager/#8-hitcallback-with-a-universal-analytics-tag

This will execute the callback function you just defined right after the *Pageview* is sent.

In the *Fields to set* option of your Pageview Tag, set:

- **Field Name** to `hitCallback`
- **Value** to `{{callBackFunction}}`

[image: Setting "hitCallback" functions in Google Tag Manager]

---

Hope it can help you move forward.